# Is there any way to change mui dialog width according to the dialogContent

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
        <Dialog
            open={true}
            sx={{ '& .MuiDialog-container': { justifyContent: 'flex-end' } }}
            PaperProps={{ sx: { m: 0, width: '100%' } }}
            fullWidth
        >
            <HeaderButtonWrapper title="A SIMPLE TITLE">
                <HeaderButton Icon={AddIcon} />
                <HeaderButton Icon={CancelIcon} />
                <HeaderButton dark Icon={SaveIcon} />
            </HeaderButtonWrapper>

            <DialogContent sx={{ padding: 0, mt: '30px', width: '1000px' }}>jfldjsklfj</DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
```

When I set the width of 1000px to DialogContent it won't work i also tried giving maxWidth and minWidth, it didn't work, but if i give minWidth to PaperProps in Dialog the width will change, but that's not I want. is there any way to fix this? I spent hours trying to fix this, but it didn't work.